# Instalação de serviços com sc.exe

Tags: delphi, services

Eu criei um ServiceApplication usando Delphi XE6

Quando eu utilizo o comando `install` (no prompt) a aplicação é instalada corretamente e o serviço pode ser iniciado.

Mas eu preciso instalar 4 instâncias do mesmo serviço no mesmo PC

Para isso utilizei o comando "sc" onde é possível definir o nome de cada instância

Quando utilizo o comando "sc" os serviços são instalados corretamente, mas nenhum deles inicia

Exemplo do comando install:

```
c:\service1\service.exe /install
```

Exemplos dos comandos sc:

```
sc.exe create Service1 binPath= "c:\service1\service.exe" DisplayName= "Service1" start= auto
sc.exe create Service2 binPath= "c:\service2\service.exe" DisplayName= "Service2" start= auto
sc.exe create Service3 binPath= "c:\service3\service.exe" DisplayName= "Service3" start= auto
sc.exe create Service4 binPath= "c:\service4\service.exe" DisplayName= "Service4" start= auto
```

O serviço funciona com o comando "sc" caso eu utilize seu nome original

Como eu posso criar um serviço no Delphi que aceite esse tipo de situação?